# My jupyter notebook refuses to open in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter Notebooks through my browser but have recently started to use Visual Studio Code for a lot of my coding. I have created a virtual environment and installed pandas, started VScode and tried to run a single line of code and I keep getting this error.

```
Failed to start Jupyter in the environment 'Python 3.9.5 64-bit (/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9)'. 
View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
```

I can not solve this and I have no idea where to go to ask for help. Can anyone get me through this?

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Yes, this is one of many errors.

```failed to start INotebook in kernel, UI Disabled = true i [Error]: Traceback (most recent call last):```

Comment: Can you post the whole log?